# How to display the results of an aggregation in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

How do you display the results of a mongodb aggregation query using node.js, express & jade

I'm not sure what I've done wrong or even if this is the correct approach.

When I attempt to access the page - it just times out?

Any idea? Or is there a better way?

app.js

```
 var mongo = require('mongodb');
 var monk = require('monk');
 var db = monk('localhost:27017/soundevents');
 var timeroute = require('./routes/timers');

 app.get('/time/starttimer', timeroute.starttimer);
```

my routes/timers.js looks like this:

```
 exports.starttimer = function(db) {
return function(req, res) {
    var aEvent = db.get('event');

    aEvent.aggregation([{$group:{_id:{"EventName":"$EventName"}}}],{}, function(e,docs) {
        res.render('time/starttimer', {title: 'Stat Timer',
         "eventlist" : docs});
    });

};

};
```

output from mongo

```
db.event.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{"EventName":"$EventName"}, UpdateTime:{$max: "$UpdateTime"}}}])


{"result" : [{"_id" : {
"EventName" : "MtnBikeRace 1"},
"UpdateTime" : 1392265180.069293},
{"_id" : {
"EventName" : "Student League"},
"UpdateTime" : 1392047321724}],
"ok" : 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example can help you.
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/jade/index.js

```
// Dummy users
var users = [
    new User('tj', 'tj@vision-media.ca')
  , new User('ciaran', 'ciaranj@gmail.com')
  , new User('aaron', 'aaron.heckmann+github@gmail.com')
];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('users', { users: users });
})
// user.jade
extends ../layout

block content
  h1 Users
  #users
    for user in users
      .user
         h2= user.name
         .email= user.email
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing I don't have the mongodb aggregation via monk written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here because I was looking for a way to aggregate results using monk.

For future reference: as of now, monk has no `.aggregate()` method, therefore this part of your code will not work (as you've indicated in a comment):

```
// there's no aggregation method.
aEvent.aggregation([{$group:{_id:{"EventName":"$EventName"}}}],{}, function(e,docs) {
                res.render('time/starttimer', {title: 'Stat Timer',
                 "eventlist" : docs});
            });
```

However,
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23966340/1447479) shows the correct way to perform an aggregation with monk. It uses the underlying native driver. In your case this would be something like the following:

```
aEvent.col.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{"EventName":"$EventName"}}}],{}, function(e,docs) {
        res.render('time/starttimer', {title: 'Stat Timer',
         "eventlist" : docs});
    });
```

If you aggregate this way, I guess you can accept [fundon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21806176/1447479).