# Issue in inserting multiple documents (Bulk Insert) into a mongoDB collection using monk in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, monk

I am trying to insert multiple documents into a collection in mongoDB database, but am only getting only one object ID as response (multiple documents are getting created in the DB).

Code:

```
exports.createRelation = function(relationDoc, db, callback) {
var relations = db.get("relations");
relations
        .insert( relationDoc )
    .error( function ( err ) {
        callback(err, null);
    })
    .success( function ( doc ){
        callback(null, doc);
   });
};
```

in this the relationDoc would be an array

Input:

```
newRelDocs_Array:  [ { 
    path: [ 53d0b191c5ac61d403b0090d ] 
    tob: 1405343247 },
  { 
    path: [ 53d0b191c5ac61d403b0090d ],
    tob: 1405343247 } ]
```

Response :

```
createRelation(): Success
createRelation_db:  { 
  _id: 546a1d6f65c05d1c37660c4c,
  tob: 1405343247
```

}

FYI, I am using NodeJS, and connection to MongoDB with monk.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say realationDoc is an array which I presume looks something like this:

```
realationDoc = [{
  id: 1,
  relation: 2
 },{
  id: 2, relation: 1
 }];
```

In monk, the insert function is not capable of the MonogoDB 2.4 built-in function Bulk Insert. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/

With your code the way it is, you are creating a collection of a single document that has 2 fields, 1 the _id which is auto-generated and the second field that is your array.

To do what you want to do, you will need to modify your code like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i<relationDoc.length;i++){
  relations.insert(relationDoc[i])
  //..add promise code for success and error stuff
}
```

Probably not as efficient as the Bulk Insert provided in the native driver, but should get you to where you need to go with monk.

Comment: No it can be accomplished in monk as I have shown, it just takes a little bit more work. Monk is lightweight, fast and awesome so in my case I can live with a bit more logic in my Javascript rather than a more functional driver.

Answer (score 0):

Monk collection wrapper provides access to the underlying collection object via `.col` field. You can use it to access the methods not implemented by Monk, such as bulk insert and aggregate:

```
var relations = db.get("relations");
var docs = [ { 
              path: [ "53d0b191c5ac61d403b0090d" ],
              tob: 1405343247
             }, {
              path: [ "53d0b191c5ac61d403b0090d" ],
              tob: 1405343247
             } ];
relations.col.insert(docs, callback);
```

Note that with `.col` you will not be able to use the promises functionality provided by monk, however. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951123/in-nodejs-how-to-output-results-from-mongodb-with-different-field-names/23966340#23966340) for more.