# Need help querying MongoDB with nodeJS. Getting undefined is not a function on the following code

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following code is giving me undefined is not a function on aggregate. My database has 22 numbers in it and I want to get the average. What am I doing wrong?

```
router.get('/mean', function(req, res) {
        var db = req.db;
        var collection = db.get('numbercollection');
        collection.aggregate([
        {$group : {_id : null, 
                   mean : {$avg : "$number"}
                  }   
        }], function(err, result) {
            console.log(result);
    });
    });
```

Just let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: Line 3 collection.aggregate. I think it is saying aggregate is not a function. But I don't know why.

Comment: What is the mongodb version you are running?

Comment: The version I'm running is 2.0.25

Comment: here is a useful advice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951123/in-nodejs-how-to-output-results-from-mongodb-with-different-field-names

Comment: @b2norma, 2.0.25 does not have aggregate support. It has been added in 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have used `db.get(collection name)` ,whereas it should be `db.collection(collection name)`.

```
router.get('/mean', function(req, res) {
   var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.collection('numbercollection');
    collection.aggregate([
    {$group : {_id : null, 
               mean : {$avg : "$number"}
              }   
    }], function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongose to connect to mongodb, then mongose doesn't directly support aggregate.

Try using

```
collection.col.aggregate([ *your query here* ])
```

[something used here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951123/in-nodejs-how-to-output-results-from-mongodb-with-different-field-names)