# MongoDB - TypeError: users.aggregate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to query a collection using `aggregate` but getting `TypeError: users.aggregate is not a function`. Here's my code:

**./app.js** (reduced to fit)

```
var express = require('express');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/mydb');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/users', users);
module.exports = app;
```

**./routes/users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  var users = req.db.get('users');

  users.aggregate([{ $match: { username: 'test0' }}], function(err, data) {
    res.json(data);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm running MongoDB version 3.2.10 and the above query works fine in the console. I've looked up solutions and they all suggest to check the MongoDB version, which I've already done. I've also tried `req.db.collection('users').aggregate` (as suggested by another post) and receive a similar error: `req.db.collection is not a function`. What am I missing?

EDIT:
Running `users.find({ username: 'test0' }, func...` works and returns correct data.

EDIT2: Added more code.

Comment: Where from `req.db.get`? Are you exporting that?

Comment: what library are you using to connect to mongodb?

Comment: @QoP I'm using monk

Comment: Deeper searching found that monk is incompatible with `aggregate` and I must use `users.col.aggregate()`. Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951123/in-nodejs-how-to-output-results-from-mongodb-with-different-field-names/

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
var app = require('express')();
var expressMongoDb = require('express-mongo-db');

app.use(expressMongoDb('mongodb://localhost/test'));

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  req.db // => Db object
});
```

Comment: I'm returning the database just fine in my `req.db.get('users')`. I'm able to `find()`, `findOne()`, `update()`, and `insert()` to it, but `aggregate` is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this. It is working in my local.

```
var app = require('express')();

const db = require('monk')('localhost/test')

app.use(function(req,res,next){
 req.db = db;
 next();
});

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  var db = req.db;
  var users = db.get('users');

  users.aggregate([
   {$match: { firstName: 'Test 2' }}
    ]).then(function(docs) {
    console.log(docs)
    })
 });

 app.listen(3010, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3010!');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I found an answer after specifically searching for monk library issues with aggregate. It turns out, it's not supported and I had to use the users collection with `users.col.aggregate()`